InvalidUpdateError: Must write to at least one of []
I'm using langgraph to track on open/new incoming emails from the mail box and I am facing the below error :
File "/python3.12/site-packages/langgraph/pregel/write.py", line 107, in _write
  self.do_write(
File "/python3.12/site-packages/langgraph/pregel/write.py", line 157, in do_write
  raise InvalidUpdateError(
langgraph.errors.InvalidUpdateError: Must write to at least one of ['checked_emails_ids', 'emails', 'action_required_emails']

langgraph version : langgraph==0.2.13
python version python3.12.4
CODE
class WorkFlow():
    def __init__(self):
        nodes = Nodes()
        workflow = StateGraph(EmailsState)

        workflow.add_node("check_new_emails", nodes.check_email)
        workflow.add_node("wait_next_run", nodes.wait_next_run)
        workflow.add_node("draft_responses", EmailFilterCrew().kickoff)

        workflow.set_entry_point("check_new_emails")
        workflow.add_conditional_edges(
                "check_new_emails",
                nodes.new_emails,
                {
                    "continue": 'draft_responses',
                    "end": 'wait_next_run'
                }
        )
        workflow.add_edge('draft_responses', 'wait_next_run')
        workflow.add_edge('wait_next_run', 'check_new_emails')
        self.app = workflow.compile()


class Nodes():
    def __init__(self):
        self.gmail = GmailToolkit()

    def check_email(self, state):
 
        print("# Checking for new emails")
        print("Begin Time")
        print(time.time())
        search = GmailSearch(api_resource=self.gmail.api_resource)
        emails = search('is:unread')
        checked_emails = state['checked_emails_ids'] if state['checked_emails_ids'] else []
        thread = []
        new_emails = []
        for email in emails:
            print(email['id'])
            if (email['id'] not in checked_emails) and (email['threadId'] not in thread) and ( os.environ['MY_EMAIL'] not in email['sender']):
                thread.append(email['threadId'])
                new_emails.append(
                    {
                        "id": email['id'],
                        "threadId": email['threadId'],
                        "snippet": email['snippet'],
                        "sender": email["sender"]
                    }
                )
        checked_emails.extend([email['id'] for email in emails])

        return {
            **state,
            "emails": new_emails,
            "checked_emails_ids": checked_emails
        }



    def wait_next_run(self, state):
        print("## Waiting for 180 seconds")
        time.sleep(60)
        return state

    def new_emails(self, state):
        if len(state['emails']) == 0:
            print("## No new emails")
            return "end"
        else:
            print("## New emails")
            return "continue"
`


class EmailsState(TypedDict):
    checked_emails_ids: list[str]
    emails: list[dict]
    action_required_emails: dict


inputs = {}
app = WorkFlow().app
app.invoke(inputs, {"recursion_limit": 1000})


What you show shouldn't raise this particular error. I suspect the issue is with EmailFilterCrew().kickoff. Please include that function definition for a definitive answer.
